# How Bootstrap class is loading in my file?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have not included the Bootstrap file into my view but still class 'btn-default' is working how?

And I am not using any gem for Bootstrap.

Here is the code -

```
<%= submit_tag "Get Order Details", class: 'btn btn-default' %>
```

Comment: Do you have the bootstrap CSS file listed in assets/stylesheets/application.css?

Comment: You mean the style still applies? This is impossible to happen 'magically'.  You should check your layout for includes( <link> to CDN with bootstrap), your public/vendor/assets and your app assets (application.css and everything included in it) as well.

Comment: Yes I checked but bootstrap is not included anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have this in your application.css

> *= require_self
>
> *= require_tree .

remove *= require_tree .

Comment: yes I have but how this can include the bootstrap.css?

Comment: at your layout the application.css included by 
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
 and the application.css require tree " assets/stylesheets/* "

Comment: yes, I got the point of "require_tree ." It basically load all files into one file during assets compilation.

Answer (score 0):

How Rails might be loading Bootstrap depends on how you've implemented Bootstrap. If it's something like my own rails template then it'll be:

in app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require bootstrap.min
```

in app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
*= require bootstrap.min
```

https://github.com/wurde/templates/blob/master/bootstrap.rb.

Since it's open source you ought to have access from within your project.

```
rake rails:template LOCATION=https://github.com/wurde/templates/raw/master/bootstrap.rb
```

Comment: I checked in my application and I have not included this file anywhere.

Comment: Glad you found the answer.